# Is it possible to simplifying these C++ template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with the following parameters

```
template <class TObj, class TMsg, void (TObj::*TMethod)( TMsg*, Link*)>
class Slot : ...
```

When I instantiate this class I then have to write

```
Slot<MyObject, MyMessage, MyObject::myMethod>
```

This implies that the class MyObject has a method named myMethod expecting MyMessage* as first argument.

Is there a way I could simplify the Slot class instantiation so that I could at least only specify the MyObject class only once ?

It would also be more intuitive if one could specify the TMsg type after the method. Something like the following would be fine:

```
Slot<MyObject::myMethod, MyMessage>
```

Comment: Is using `MyObject::operator()` an option?

Comment: No because there might be different methods in MyObject for which we want to create a Slot. The method name and its message type are important because overloading is legit in C++. The Link* parameter is however always present in the methods and a base class.

Comment: @chmike: You can overload `()` with many implementations, each with different set of parameters. See my answer.

Comment: I know but the difference between the different operator() is made only on the parameter. But the user should be able to define many different methods exposed as Slot hooks and distinguish them by their name also, not only their parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If using `decltype` is an option...

```
template <typename M, typename O, void (O::*Method)(M*, Link*)>
Slot<O, M, Method> slot_type(Method);
```

And then:

```
decltype(slot_type<MyMessage>(MyObject::mymethod))
```

not... that this is much shorter... but it does avoid the redundancy.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. Slot is a class, not a function. It is used to define a member variable type which makes it a connection point to the method defined in the template argument. Slot<MyObject, MyMessage, MyObject::myMethod> m_mySlotMemberVariable;

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `operator()`  for all pair of parameters types (`TMsg` and `Link`) to be passed to the slot handler.

```
struct MyObject
{
   //handlers
   void operator()(AMsg* msg, Link* link);  //handler 1
   void operator()(BMsg* msg, Link* link);  //handler 2
   void operator()(CMsg* msg, Link* link);  //handler 3
};
```

And then use it as:

```
Slot<MyObject, AMsg> aslot;
Slot<MyObject, BMsg> bslot;
Slot<MyObject, CMsg> cslot;
```

where you `Slot` as:

```
template <class TObj, class TMsg>
class Slot 
{
   TMsg *pMsg;
   Link *pLink;
   void f()
   {
      TObj slotHander;

      slotHandler(pMsg, pLink); //it calls the appropriate handler
   }
};
```

Comment: No doubt that it works, but it doesn't answer to the question. The object can have only one void operator()(AMsg* msg, Link* link) method. Beside, message polymorphism will generate ambiguities on which the compiler may choke.

Comment: @chmike: No. The object can have as many `operator()` as you want, like in my example.

Comment: What I need is that the user may define method1( AMsg* ) {}, method2( AMsg* ){}, ... in the same class and define a specific slot member variable for each of these methods. Each method would of course have a specific behavior. This is why using the operator() is not an option.